# Is it possible to create a class inherited from AVCaptureDevice?

Tags: ios, inheritance, avcapturedevice

I am trying to create a class inherited from AVCaptureDevice like this

in MyClass.h file

```
@interface MyClass : AVCaptureDevice
```

but how can I assign the AVCaptureDevice instance to "self" in init method?

Here is my approach now (doesn't work...)

in MyClass.m file

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
       NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
       AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [devices firstObject];
       self = (MyClass*)captureDevice;
       [self myClassMethod];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) myClassMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Doesn't work");
}
```

I got `NSInvalidArgumentException`, reason: '`-[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice test]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance", which make sense because test is not the method in AVCaptureDevice.

Another approach I did before is containing AVCaptureDevice in MyClass class, which works.

But I still wonder whether I miss some good approach to implement this thought.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVCaptureDevice is not intended for subclassing.
There is no way to create a concrete instance of this class without using one of the class methods:

```
+ devices
+ deviceWithUniqueID:
+ defaultDeviceWithMediaType:
+ devicesWithMediaType:
```

Your options are either contain the instance and wrap access to it, create a proxy or some wrapper for it, or even a category.